# Kubernetes Pod IPs change when cluster is re-deployed

Tags: kubernetes, ip

I am deploying the microservice benchmark [here](https://github.com/delimitrou/DeathStarBench/tree/master/socialNetwork) using helm charts.

However, when I uninstall the helm chart and re-install (basically, equivalent to re-deploying all kubernetes pods), the IP addresses change. Specifically, the IP addresses keep on increasing on subsequent runs. Here is the workflow:

```bash
$ helm install social-network ./socialnetwork
$ kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=PodName:.metadata.name,PodIP:.status.podIP
PodName                                   PodIP
compose-post-service-866f6d7b74-rzqh6     10.244.0.198   
home-timeline-redis-7994f7cb85-8fjlh      10.244.0.199
...
$ helm uninstall social-network
...
$ helm install social-network ./socialnetwork
$ kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=PodName:.metadata.name,PodIP:.status.podIP
PodName                                   PodIP      
compose-post-service-866f6d7b74-2d4jf     10.244.0.254   
home-timeline-redis-7994f7cb85-dc8jn      10.244.0.250
```

My concern is that for my development and testing, I need to re-deploy the benchmark several times.

Is there a limit to how many times I can restart the application? If so, how can I force Kubernetes to reuse the same IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a limit to how many times I can restart the application?

No, there is no limit.

> If so, how can I force Kubernetes to reuse the same IP addresses?

There is no need for that since inside the CNI (Container Network Interface, your network plugin e.g. Calico, Cilium, ...) there is an [IPAM](https://www.cni.dev/plugins/current/ipam/) (IP Address Management) running, which takes care of assigning a subnet to a node, which then is used to give a Pod an IP via DHCP.

If you would like to connect to your pod, you should use a [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Comment: Understood. It already has a service IP but I am trying to also trace the IP addresses, so the changing IPs were a problem. Anyways, if there is no limit, then it is fine for my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes assigns a new IP to every started POD. That is done by design, so you should not make any assumptions on the POD IP, but rather use [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) (or possibly Pod's hostname) for communication.